# How to fix Strange characters issue in STS console when running Spring Boot application?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I had no problems with the console output earlier. Suddenly these strange characters started appearing in the console this week.

Actual:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Those look like color codes which the Eclipse console does not support.

Comment: @greg-449, Is there a way to disable these color codes?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use STS so I don't know

Comment: See https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/color-logs.html

Answer (score 2):

These are the ANSI color codes that Spring Boot supports to show a nicely colored console output. You can enable and disable this in the launch configuration for your Spring boot application, there is a checkbox for that.

In order to display the colored output, you need to have the ANSI Console plugin installed in your environment. This is done by default if you download an STS distribution. If you installed STS into an existing Eclipse installation, this extension isn't installed by default, but you can grab that from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse STS, navigate to console view. Click on the gear icon (Show Ansi Console Preferences). Click on Restore Defaults. This has solved the issue in STS.

[image: eclipse_sts_screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse STS, click Window -> Preferences -> Ansi console -> and finally click on Restore Defaults and Apply

Comment: What is the default setting that allows this issue to be fixed?